# How to manage authentication of a user through a vue router and a server-provided JWT token?

Tags: node.js, rest, vue.js, jwt, vue-router

I am building a web app using vue/webpack for the front end and node.js/express on back end. The node.js back end is exposing REST APIs that are used by the front end to login, logout and other CRUD-like operations.

On server side, the login REST API is setting a JWT token and redirects to the vue application home path.
On front end side, the vue components access (including home) is guarded by the beforeEach method of the vue router (based on sample from [here](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/how-do-i-redirect-user-to-proper-page/8243/2)).

My question is, from within my vue application, how can I access the JWT token (set by the login REST API in the HTTP Headers of the response) and store it in my vuex store so that my vue components can use it?

Thanks for your help!
PS: I am using node.js 8.5, Vue 2.4.4, Vue Router 2.7, Vuex 2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

Use [Axios Interceptors](https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors):

```
import { defaults, get } from 'lodash';
import axios from 'axios';
import store from 'vuex-store';
import def from './default';

export const connection = (options = {}) => {
  def.headers = { Authorization: store.getters.auth.getToken() };
  const instance = axios.create(defaults(def, options));

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    function (response) {
      const newtoken = get(response, 'headers.authorization');
      if (newtoken) store.dispatch('setToken', newtoken);
      console.log(response.data);
      return response;
    },
    function (error) {
      switch (error.response.status) {
        case 401:
          store.dispatch('logoff');
          break;
        default:
          console.log(error.response);
      }
      return Promise.reject(error);
    }
  );

  return instance;
};
```